# Advanced Mutivarible Calculus check?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Complete the following statement: The statement that a set M is not infinite means…

This is my attempt:

The statement that a set M is not infinite means…

M is t finite
Number of elements in M are finite.
we calculate the number of element in set M
Every one-to-one function from M into itself is onto.
Every surjective function from M onto itself is one-to-one.

Do you think that is enough? Help me complete please

Comment: You are bombarding this forum with so many questions all with tags *multivariable* calculus.  But none of your questions fit that classification.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that $M$ can be mapped bijectively onto $\emptyset$ or $\{1, \dotsc, n \}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.